# How to avoid duplicated values in a column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using the below code to fetch data from two tables. But I can see some duplicate values in the column `data1` and `data2`.

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.student_id,a.class,a.sub_id,
      stringagg(a.sub_num) OVER (PARTITION BY a.student_id, a.class, a.sub_id 
                           ORDER BY NLSSORT(a.sub_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                          ) AS data1,
      stringagg(b.date) OVER (PARTITION BY b.sub_id 
                        ORDER BY NLSSORT(b.date, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                          ) AS data2
from tsg_class a JOIN tsg_date b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
                                and a.class = b.class
                                and a.sub_id = b.sub_id
where a.student_id = 38147;
```

---

My result looks like in the attached image:

[image]

The Data1 and Data2 have duplicated values like `22**** 22**** 22**** 22**** 555555 555555 555555 555555` and `001 001 7WW 7WW D04 D04 MS7 MS7`

But I wanted it to be like `22**** 55555` and `001 7ww D04 MS7`.

Please suggest.

Comment: which database are you using, oracle/sql server/mysql etc

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph "PL/SQL (Procedural Language/Structured Query Language) is Oracle Corporation's procedural language extension for SQL."

Answer (score 0):

Which database do you use? PL/SQL suggests Oracle, but there's no `stringagg` function there - we use `listagg` nowadays. Recent Oracle version supports `listagg(distinct ...)` which solves your problem.

Otherwise, **first** select `distinct` values from the table, **then** apply aggregation to already distinct data set.

---

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select listagg(job, ',') within group (order by job) jobs from emp;

JOBS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ANALYST,ANALYST,CLERK,CLERK,CLERK,CLERK,MANAGER,MANAGER,MANAGER,PRESIDENT,SALESM
AN,SALESMAN,SALESMAN,SALESMAN
```

This is what you want, but your Oracle database version doesn't support it:

```
SQL> select listagg(distinct job, ',') within group (order by job) jobs from emp;
select listagg(distinct job, ',') within group (order by job) jobs from emp
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function
```

This is what you should do:

```
SQL> select listagg(job, ',') within group (order by job) jobs
  2  from (select distinct job from emp);

JOBS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ANALYST,CLERK,MANAGER,PRESIDENT,SALESMAN

SQL>
```

Comment: i tried with listagg (distinct) it is not working. I mean i get error ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function
30482. 00000 -  "DISTINCT option not allowed for this function"

Comment: I am using Oracle database.

Comment: As I said, **recent** Oracle database version (19c) supports it. Which version do you use? If lower, it can't work so you'll have to apply what I suggested in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: I added an example; have a look, please.

Comment: I have used stringagg_distinct(a.sub_num) and it worked.

Comment: OK. As I said: STRINGAGG or STRINGAGG_DISTINCT aren't standard Oracle functions. That's something that exists in your database. Anyway, I'm glad you made it work. Thank you for letting us know.